# What the easiest way to handle licensing for .NET applications?

Tags: c#, .net, windows-7, licensing

I'm about to deliver my freelance Windows Forms project.

What is the easiest way to handle licensing? My target machine doesn't have internet access so I don't think validating via a webservice would be the best course of action.

I just don't want them to copy my program and run it on other machines, or even sell it themselves.

Comment: No stipulations regarding licenses. This is a pretty voice-only contract. It's for a friend of the family (nuns actually).

Comment: @Oded: If this helps any this is a 1.2k$ software project.

Comment: @Sergio - cost is not really relevant here. It's about the agreement and the legalese.

Comment: Try This [Trial Maker](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/cs/Trial_Maker.aspx)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are so many ways of doing it and they all depend on what your target audience/deployment environment is going to be.

Since you can't call home, you will need to rely on serial numbers. If you have a client/server architecture, then you can store the registrations on the server and clients can check them.

If it's just a client only app then you can 1) use serial numbers 2) have them generate a serial request which uses their MAC address or some other unique identifier to determine the machine they are installing on. This way when you issue a serial based on their request, it will only work on the machine in which the request was generated.

Comment: request/response serial #'s is a good idea in a disconnected scenario. This is how Corel, Adobe and so many other companies protect their software.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a dongle, i think it's the safest way.
A dongle can hold sensitive parts of your application and the application will not run until the dongle plugged in usb port, you should read more about it and i think there is a special dongle for dotnet apps.
Trust me we use it in our company form long time.

Comment: I mean you can attach each version of your software with a dongle and i think it,s cheap

Comment: Dongles are expensive and usually only acceptable for extremely large (Expensive) applications. I havent really seen them outside of engineering type of apps such as CAD/#D Modeling, CNC controllers. Dongles must be purchased and coded for or developed in house. both of which are expensive and add to the cost and frustrate users.

Comment: Yeah maybe maybe it's little expensive, but it's price to pay for safety. i don't want to say dongles names but there is new dotnet dongles that picks the sensitive parts of your app by it self and do the work you don't have to do anything, maybe there is better ways but keep this one in mind as a last choice.

Comment: Not saying they aren't worthy of mentioning because they certainly are. I guess we need to know what type of app this is an how much is it for a license? $30 deaktop app doesn't warrant a dongle but a $1300 desktop app does.

Comment: Yeah your right sure we use dongle because our software worth at least $1550.

Answer (score 1):

If the terms of your software say that's how it is licensed, then that should be enough.

Don't forget that since you wrote this software, chances are good that you will be called back for fixes/enhancements. This should give you *plenty* of opportunity to see if your license is being abused.

Answer (score 1):

There are obfuscation solutions that provide built in licensing security. You can try one of those. XenoCode is one of them. http://www.xenocode.com/

Answer (score 0):

Include an installer for your software. This installer should set some registry keys that identify this machine as having a valid installation; your program will then interrogate those keys and determine if it should run.

The question of how to produce those keys and what they should be is answered by how esoteric you want to get. The simpler they are, the easier for you to implement, but the simpler for them to spoof. If you just want to make it easier to buy a license than to spoof the install, you can do that by having the installer require a license key that can be decrypted by it into something it will expect (like the name the user also typed in). Then it can encrypt and set a registry key that your program will decrypt when it starts to determine a valid install. This can be spoofed, and without Internet access it does not prove that one person is not using the same key on many computers.

If you want to make sure that EVERY installation is individually licensed, without fail, you must have internet access, because your installer or your program itself will have to talk to a centralized web service (or a license key server, common for enterprise installs) to determine that the key is genuine and not currently in use by another computer.

Comment: What keeps one from changing the registry and bypassing the installer?

Comment: Not much, except they have to know what the installer is writing to the registry. If the installer encrypts its registry key, they need a valid install to clone. If the installer encrypts something machine-specific that the application can check, they can't just copy the registry key from a valid install; they would have to reflect into your installer to discover its secrets, then replicate it to generate spoofed registry info. Still crackable, but by this point you're well beyond the capabilities of the average user.

Comment: they can simply use RegMon (freely available and easy to use tool) to see what is being read/written and no reflection required. It all depends on how secure you want to be. Apps should have their own validation and not rely on installers to secure them.

Comment: @Titan: They can see what's being written to the reg, but if that is an encrypted value they don't know what the cleartext is; all they can do then is copy/paste. If you make that string something machine-specific (or even installation-specific), they cannot copy/paste, requiring them to dig into your assembly to get the secret information required to replicate it.